# Reset a docker image to initial state

Tags: docker

I'm new to docker and recently I tried to use setup [openstreetmap-tileserver](https://github.com/Overv/openstreetmap-tile-server). I tried a manual installation by cloning the project and run `docker build -t SampleMap` and `docker run -v openstreetmap-data:/var/lib/postgresql/10/main SampleMap import` and then run the proper command to run the container. I got three images using `docker image ls`:

```
ubuntu
none
SampleMap
```

Everything worked fined. Next, I tried to erase the DB and do the whole process for a new map (a different `.osm.pbf` file). I removed the image `SampleMap` (with `docker image rm`) and tried to do the whole process again but the problem is all the DB tables still exist. It seems that all the changes are written into the Ubuntu image rather than the `SampleMap`. I'm asking generally is there any way that I can reset the whole Ubuntu image to its initial state? It seems that all the changes are permanent in the Ubuntu image.

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# Based on
# https://switch2osm.org/manually-building-a-tile-server-18-04-lts/

# Set up environment
ENV TZ=UTC
ENV AUTOVACUUM=on
ENV UPDATES=disabled
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

# Install dependencies
RUN echo "deb [ allow-insecure=yes ] http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ bionic-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list \
  && apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends --allow-unauthenticated \
  apache2 \
  apache2-dev \
  autoconf \
  build-essential \
  bzip2 \
  cmake \
  fonts-noto-cjk \
  fonts-noto-hinted \
  fonts-noto-unhinted \
  clang \
  gdal-bin \
  git-core \
  libagg-dev \
  libboost-all-dev \
  libbz2-dev \
  libcairo-dev \
  libcairomm-1.0-dev \
  libexpat1-dev \
  libfreetype6-dev \
  libgdal-dev \
  libgeos++-dev \
  libgeos-dev \
  libgeotiff-epsg \
  libicu-dev \
  liblua5.3-dev \
  libmapnik-dev \
  libpq-dev \
  libproj-dev \
  libprotobuf-c0-dev \
  libtiff5-dev \
  libtool \
  libxml2-dev \
  lua5.3 \
  make \
  mapnik-utils \
  nodejs \
  npm \
  postgis \
  postgresql-10 \
  postgresql-10-postgis-2.5 \
  postgresql-10-postgis-2.5-scripts \
  postgresql-contrib-10 \
  protobuf-c-compiler \
  python-mapnik \
  sudo \
  tar \
  ttf-unifont \
  unzip \
  wget \
  zlib1g-dev \
  osmosis \
  osmium-tool \
  cron \
  python3-psycopg2 python3-shapely python3-lxml \
&& apt-get clean autoclean \
&& apt-get autoremove --yes \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/{apt,dpkg,cache,log}/

# Set up renderer user
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" renderer
USER renderer

# Install latest osm2pgsql
RUN mkdir /home/renderer/src
WORKDIR /home/renderer/src
RUN git clone https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql.git
WORKDIR /home/renderer/src/osm2pgsql
RUN mkdir build
WORKDIR /home/renderer/src/osm2pgsql/build
RUN cmake .. \
  && make -j $(nproc)
USER root
RUN make install
USER renderer

# Install and test Mapnik
RUN python -c 'import mapnik'

# Install mod_tile and renderd
WORKDIR /home/renderer/src
RUN git clone -b switch2osm https://github.com/SomeoneElseOSM/mod_tile.git
WORKDIR /home/renderer/src/mod_tile
RUN ./autogen.sh \
  && ./configure \
  && make -j $(nproc)
USER root
RUN make -j $(nproc) install \
  && make -j $(nproc) install-mod_tile \
  && ldconfig
USER renderer

# Configure stylesheet
WORKDIR /home/renderer/src
RUN git clone https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto.git
WORKDIR /home/renderer/src/openstreetmap-carto
USER root
RUN npm install -g carto
USER renderer
RUN carto project.mml > mapnik.xml

# Load shapefiles
WORKDIR /home/renderer/src/openstreetmap-carto
RUN scripts/get-shapefiles.py

# Configure renderd
USER root
RUN sed -i 's/renderaccount/renderer/g' /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf \
  && sed -i 's/hot/tile/g' /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf
USER renderer

# Configure Apache
USER root
RUN mkdir /var/lib/mod_tile \
  && chown renderer /var/lib/mod_tile \
  && mkdir /var/run/renderd \
  && chown renderer /var/run/renderd
RUN echo "LoadModule tile_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_tile.so" >> /etc/apache2/conf-available/mod_tile.conf \
  && a2enconf mod_tile
COPY apache.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
COPY leaflet-demo.html /var/www/html/index.html
RUN ln -sf /proc/1/fd/1 /var/log/apache2/access.log \
  && ln -sf /proc/1/fd/2 /var/log/apache2/error.log

# Configure PosgtreSQL
COPY postgresql.custom.conf.tmpl /etc/postgresql/10/main/
RUN chown -R postgres:postgres /var/lib/postgresql \
  && chown postgres:postgres /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.custom.conf.tmpl \
  && echo "\ninclude 'postgresql.custom.conf'" >> /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf

# copy update scripts
COPY openstreetmap-tiles-update-expire /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/openstreetmap-tiles-update-expire \
    && mkdir /var/log/tiles \
    && chmod a+rw /var/log/tiles \
    && ln -s /home/renderer/src/mod_tile/osmosis-db_replag /usr/bin/osmosis-db_replag \
    && echo "*  *    * * *   renderer    openstreetmap-tiles-update-expire\n" >> /etc/crontab

# install trim_osc.py helper script
USER renderer
RUN cd ~/src \
    && git clone https://github.com/zverik/regional \
    && cd regional \
    && git checkout 612fe3e040d8bb70d2ab3b133f3b2cfc6c940520 \
    && chmod u+x ~/src/regional/trim_osc.py

# Start running
USER root
COPY run.sh /
COPY indexes.sql /
ENTRYPOINT ["/run.sh"]
CMD []

EXPOSE 80 5432
```

And here is my `run.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

function CreatePostgressqlConfig()
{
  cp /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.custom.conf.tmpl /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.custom.conf
  sudo -u postgres echo "autovacuum = $AUTOVACUUM" >> /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.custom.conf
  cat /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.custom.conf
}

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    ls /home/renderer
    echo "usage: <import|run>"
    echo "commands:"
    echo "    import: Set up the database and import /data.osm.pbf"
    echo "    run: Runs Apache and renderd to serve tiles at /tile/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    echo "environment variables:"
    echo "    THREADS: defines number of threads used for importing / tile rendering"
    echo "    UPDATES: consecutive updates (enabled/disabled)"
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$1" = "import" ]; then
    # Initialize PostgreSQL
    CreatePostgressqlConfig
    service postgresql start
    sudo -u postgres createuser renderer
    sudo -u postgres createdb -E UTF8 -O renderer gis
    sudo -u postgres psql -d gis -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"
    sudo -u postgres psql -d gis -c "CREATE EXTENSION hstore;"
    sudo -u postgres psql -d gis -c "ALTER TABLE geometry_columns OWNER TO renderer;"
    sudo -u postgres psql -d gis -c "ALTER TABLE spatial_ref_sys OWNER TO renderer;"

    # Download Luxembourg as sample if no data is provided
    if [ ! -f /data.osm.pbf ]; then
        echo "WARNING: No import file at /data.osm.pbf, so importing iran-latest as example..."
        wget -nv http://download.geofabrik.de/north-america/canada-latest.osm.pbf -O /data.osm.pbf
        # wget -nv http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/luxembourg.poly -O /data.poly
    fi

    # determine and set osmosis_replication_timestamp (for consecutive updates)
    osmium fileinfo /data.osm.pbf > /var/lib/mod_tile/data.osm.pbf.info
    osmium fileinfo /data.osm.pbf | grep 'osmosis_replication_timestamp=' | cut -b35-44 > /var/lib/mod_tile/replication_timestamp.txt
    REPLICATION_TIMESTAMP=$(cat /var/lib/mod_tile/replication_timestamp.txt)

    # initial setup of osmosis workspace (for consecutive updates)
    sudo -u renderer openstreetmap-tiles-update-expire $REPLICATION_TIMESTAMP

    # copy polygon file if available
    if [ -f /data.poly ]; then
        sudo -u renderer cp /data.poly /var/lib/mod_tile/data.poly
    fi

    # Import data
    sudo -u renderer osm2pgsql -d gis --create --slim -G --hstore --tag-transform-script /home/renderer/src/openstreetmap-carto/openstreetmap-carto.lua -C 2048 --number-processes ${THREADS:-4} -S /home/renderer/src/openstreetmap-carto/openstreetmap-carto.style /data.osm.pbf

    # Create indexes
    sudo -u postgres psql -d gis -f indexes.sql

    service postgresql stop

    exit 0
fi

if [ "$1" = "run" ]; then
    # Clean /tmp
    rm -rf /tmp/*

    # Fix postgres data privileges
    chown postgres:postgres /var/lib/postgresql -R

    # Initialize PostgreSQL and Apache
    CreatePostgressqlConfig
    service postgresql start
    service apache2 restart

    # Configure renderd threads
    sed -i -E "s/num_threads=[0-9]+/num_threads=${THREADS:-4}/g" /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf

    # start cron job to trigger consecutive updates
    if [ "$UPDATES" = "enabled" ]; then
      /etc/init.d/cron start
    fi

    # Run
    sudo -u renderer renderd -f -c /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf
    service postgresql stop

    exit 0
fi

echo "invalid command"
exit 1
```

Comment: `docker volume rm openstreetmap-data`then recreate your container

Comment: This sort of question will generally be easier to reason about, and your scripts vastly simpler, if you split out PostgreSQL, the Apache front-end, and the update job into separate containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a container from your image, you mount a volume, using the `-v` option:
`docker run -v openstreetmap-data:/var/lib/postgresql/10/main SampleMap import`

Your persistent data is stored in `openstreetmap-data`. That file/folder is not in your container (that is created every time), it is mounted from your host's filesystem. That's why it persists